# What exactly triggers recipe/construction discovery in Valheim?

Tags: valheim

I've always thought that you get a recipe/construction when you pick up ("discover") the last of all the ingredients involved in the recipe.

Lately however, I've spent a lot of time without a hammer to save inventory space on long expeditions. I have noticed that I often get new recipes when I pick up the hammer again after a long trip, or when I craft a new hammer.

It seems thus that the new ingredients I found during the trip were not enough by themselves, but the hammer is also involved. I always assumed that having had a hammer once would last "forever" but these observations speak against it.

Does someone know the exact mechanism that triggers the discovery?

Comment: I believe certain items trigger recipe gain. As an example, you won't learn about the silver knife until you pick up specifically a silver ingot. But some recipes are more specific, like Frostner not being learned until you pick up Ymir flesh for the first time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's just a bug with recipe popups not displaying when they're supposed to. I've gotten the popups when putting on a helmet.

Comment: do you use mods? a mod could alter the game's behaviour. other than that it could be a bug or oversight, maybe the devs assumed that there is always a hammer in your inventory.

Comment: @DennisChristian no, no mods used.

Comment: Then only Odin or the developers themselves can answer what exactly triggers recipes.